# Rails tables data comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two `<td>` in a rails app:

```html
<td id="ticketsRemaining">
  <%= concert.tickets_remaining %>
</td>

<td id="ticketsAvailable">
  <%= concert.tickets_available %>
</td>
```

I want to add "warning" Bootstrap class to `ticketsRemaining` when the number of `ticketsRemaining` is 20% or less than `ticketsAvailable`. And add "danger" bootstrap class to it when the number of `ticketsRemaining` is 0.

Please help! I tried doing it in JavaScript but I'm required to use Ruby only.

Comment: If you want that on runtime, then you have to use JS, otherwise on every time page refresh you can do that using a helper method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td id="ticketsRemaining" class="<%= concert.calculate_class_type %>">
  <%= concert.tickets_remaining %>
</td>

<td id="ticketsAvailable">
  <%= concert.tickets_available %>
</td>
```

in your concert model:

```
def calculate_class_type
  pc = (tickets_remaining/tickets_available).to_f.round(2)
  if pc.zero?
    'danger'
  elsif pc <= 0.2
    'warning'
  else
    ''
  end
end
```